# Form isn't get submitted when i put the code to hide .php in .htaccess file

Tags: php

I have put the code to hide .php from the url. For example, it was before [www.abc.com/service.php](http://www.abc.com/service.php), After putting the code in .htaccess file, it become [www.abc.com/service](http://www.abc.com/service)

But with that, my form aren't get submitting. Like when i try to login, my login form do nothing. When i remove the code in .htaccess, then my login form works.

My form code is like this

```
<form method="post" action="inc/login.php">
```

Here is .htaccess code

```
RewriteEngine On 

RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^events/([a-z0-9\-]+)$ /new_events.php?slug=$1 [L]

RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} 80
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?zink\.la
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.zink.la/$1 [R,L]

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} /([^.]+)\.php [NC]
RewriteRule ^ /%1 [NC,L,R]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php -f
RewriteRule ^ %{REQUEST_URI}.php [NC,L]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www.zink.la [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.zink.la/$1 [L,R=301]

ErrorDocument 404 https://www.zink.la/404.php

<IfModule mod_expires.c>
    ExpiresActive on
 
    ExpiresByType image/jpg "access plus 1 month"
    ExpiresByType image/jpeg "access plus 1 month"
    ExpiresByType image/gif "access plus 1 month"
    ExpiresByType image/png "access plus 1 month"
</IfModule>

<IfModule mod_expires.c>
    ExpiresActive on
 
    ExpiresByType text/javascript "access plus 1 month"
    ExpiresByType application/javascript "access plus 1 month"
</IfModule>

<IfModule mod_expires.c>
    ExpiresActive on
 
    ExpiresByType text/css "access plus 1 month"
</IfModule>
```

Comment: I don't think `THE_REQUEST` is the correct variable to use, https://stackoverflow.com/a/17212293/231316

Comment: THE_REQUEST might be ok to use in that context in order to force the .php to be stripped. But If you want it removed, you should remove it from your HTML entirely. modify the html to use `action="inc/login"` without the .php, then you save many round trips with redirects.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Per comment of  Michael Berkowski, i removed the .php in my form actions and it worked.
Thank you  Michael Berkowski

Comment: It still should have worked with .php in the form action, but not having that is better anyway. Does it still work correctly to redirect and strip the .php if you directly visit `service.php` ?

Comment: It wasn't working with .php. I tried it but after removing that it worked